# how to set string variable as property in subquery

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have the following objects:

```
var authors1 = new List<Author>() {
    new Author{ FirstName = "William", LastName = "Smith" },
    new Author{ FirstName = "Fred", LastName = "Jones" }
};

var authors2 = new List<Author>() {
    new Author{ FirstName = "Brian", LastName = "Brains" },
    new Author{ FirstName = "Billy", LastName = "TheKid" }
};

var books = new List<Book>() {
    new Book{ Title = "JAVA", Description = "Description Java", Authors = authors1 },
    new Book{ Title = "PHP", Description = "Description PHP", Authors = authors2 },
};
```

I want to create a subquery filtering by author. I know that I can do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Book> list = books.Where(x => x.Authors.Where(j => j.FirstName == "William").Any());
```

But I would like to use the authors property as string var.

```
var entity = "Authors"
IEnumerable<Book> list = books.Where(x => x[entity].Where(j => j.FirstName == "William").Any());
```

This is not working.

Comment: Why don't you use OR condition.
Where( x => x.Authors(...) || x.Title(...) || x.Description(...))

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? See [the XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Would other objects/properties be searchable for "William"?

Comment: this is a specific case. It would be a generic search. That is the reason why I want to use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to do this... But here is one way you could reach what you want with reflection:

```
public bool HasAuthorWithName(Book book, string authName)
{
    // Retrieve list of class' properties
    var p = book.GetType().GetProperties();
        
    // Get list of authors prop by name             
    var entity = "Authors";
    var lstAuthors = p.First(x => x.Name == entity).GetValue(book, null) as List<Author>;
        
    // Filter by author's name
    if (lstAuthors != null && lstAuthors.Any())
    {
        return lstAuthors.Any(j => j.FirstName == authName);
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Now you can call this method:

```
IEnumerable<Book> list = books.Where(x => HasAuthorWithName(x, "William"));
```